# Unable to compare two dates

Tags: php, arrays

I have an `array` and using `foreach` loop I am trying to check if the `dinner_date` matches the previous index `dinner_date` and if they don't i am assigning `yes` to variable called `$newDate` This is what the output looks line

```
array:4 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "request_id" => "48"
    "dinner_date" => "2016-05-16T10:00:00"
    "new_date" => "no"
  ]
  1 => array:3 [▼
    "request_id" => "51"
    "dinner_date" => "2016-05-16T10:00:00"
    "new_date" => "no"
  ]
  2 => array:3 [▼
    "request_id" => "50"
    "dinner_date" => "2016-05-27T10:00:00"
    "new_date" => "no"
  ]
  3 => array:3 [▼
    "request_id" => "52"
    "dinner_date" => "2016-05-27T10:00:00"
    "new_date" => "no"
  ]
]
```

This is my `foreach` loop

```
$dinnerDetails = array();
$lastDinnerDate = '';
$newDate = '';
foreach ($invitations as $invitation) {
    $lastDinnerDate = $invitation['dinner_date'];
    if ($invitation['dinner_date'] > $lastDinnerDate) {
        $newDate = 'yes';

    } else {
        $newDate = 'no';
    }

    $dinnerDetails[] = array(
        'request_id' => $invitation['request_id'],
        'dinner_date' => $invitation['dinner_date'],
        'new_dinner' => $newDate
    );
}
```

So as you can see in index `2` of array output it says `new_date => no` it should actually be `yes` because `dinner_date` of this index is different than the `dinner_date` of the index above.

So am I doing wrong here?

Comment: in your case they both are same, you need to store `$lastDinnerDate = $invitation['dinner_date'];` after the condition.

Comment: Assign `$lastDinnerDate = $invitation['dinner_date'];` as the very last action in the loop, not as the first

Comment: What's the format of your dinner date?

Comment: @MichelFeldheim `$invitation['dinner_date']` is `datetime`

Comment: @MarkBaker that assigns `yes` to all

Comment: @Saadia - yet your accepted answer is doing exactly what I said to do

Comment: @MarkBaker yes but the answer made use of `strtotime` that i was not using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment: In your case they both are same, you need to store `$lastDinnerDate = $invitation['dinner_date'];` after the condition.

Add one more condition `$lastDinnerDate != ""` to your if condition and assign the `` after the in condition.

> For the comparison you need to convert the datetime into timestamp.

```
foreach ($invitations as $invitation) {

    if (strtotime($invitation['dinner_date']) > $lastDinnerDate && $lastDinnerDate != "") {
        $newDate = 'yes';

    } else {
        $newDate = 'no';
    }
    $lastDinnerDate = strtotime($invitation['dinner_date']);

    $dinnerDetails[] = array(
        'request_id' => $invitation['request_id'],
        'dinner_date' => $invitation['dinner_date'],
        'new_dinner' => $newDate
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped

Comment: Comparison of DateTime objects can actually be done with arithmetic operators. PHP overloads comparison operators internally

Comment: So if i don't convert the time to timestamp it will works fine as you say. @MichelFeldheim. Right?

Answer (score 1):

Change it to this :

```
$lastDinnerDate = '';
foreach ($invitations as $invitation) {
    $lastDinnerDate = $invitation['dinner_date'];
    $newDate = 'no';
    if ($lastDinnerDate != "") {
        if ($invitation['dinner_date'] > $lastDinnerDate) {
            $newDate = 'yes';
        } else {
            $newDate = 'no';
        }
    }
    $lastDinnerDate = $invitation['dinner_date'];
    $dinnerDetails[] = array(
        'request_id' => $invitation['request_id'],
        'dinner_date' => $invitation['dinner_date'],
        'new_dinner' => $newDate
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem here is that you're storing the same values in every cycle, so the two dates will be the same every time, thus the execution will never reach the "yes" branch.

Also, you're trying to apply an arithmetic comparison operator for two strings, which will provide fake results:

```
$invitation['dinner_date'] > $lastDinnerDate
```

All you need to do is to use **[strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)**. It basically parses any date format into a timestamp, which you can compare regularly:

```
strtotime($invitation['dinner_date']) > strtotime($lastDinnerDate)
```

It can parse a wide variety of date strings, for more info, visit the **[datetime.formats](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php)** in the official manual.

Comment: Yes, i tried that and did not work, @Frayne answer helped and it works now, many thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Yeah, the string comparison is a nice touch there. If the date format will not change, it will be perfect!